Can't get JsDiff to work properly for custom diffing in vscode
I  tried creating a custom diffing functionality for my vscode extension because vscode doesn't support showing all diffs in file at once,i think git uses it's own code for diffing too so i had to implement mine using the library jsdiff but currently the diff doesn't include the added lines and only displays the original text and also adds an orange decorator all over the place when i only have a added and removed text decorations which are green and red which has really left me confused,here's my implementation:
async function showInlineDiff(fileUri: vscode.Uri, newCode: string) {
    const currentFileContent = await vscode.workspace.fs.readFile(fileUri);
    const originalText = Buffer.from(currentFileContent).toString('utf-8');

    // Normalize line endings
    const normalizedOriginalText = originalText.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');
    const normalizedNewCode = newCode.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n');

    console.log("normal normal",normalizedNewCode,"broker",normalizedOriginalText);

    const diffs = diffLines(normalizedOriginalText, normalizedNewCode);

    const editor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(fileUri);

    const addedDecorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)',
        isWholeLine: true,
    });

    const removedDecorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        //textDecoration: 'line-through',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
        isWholeLine: true,
    });

    const addedRanges: vscode.Range[] = [];
    const removedRanges: vscode.Range[] = [];
    let lineNumber = 0;

    for (const part of diffs) {
        const lines = part.value.split('\n');

        if (part.added) {
            lines.forEach((line, i) => {
                if (i < lines.length - 1) {
                    addedRanges.push(
                        new vscode.Range(lineNumber + i, 0, lineNumber + i, line.length)
                    );
                }
            });
        } else if (part.removed) {
            lines.forEach((line, i) => {
                if (i < lines.length - 1) {
                    removedRanges.push(
                        new vscode.Range(lineNumber + i, 0, lineNumber + i, line.length)
                    );
                }
            });
        }

        if (!part.removed) {
            
            lineNumber += lines.length - 1;
        }
    }

    

    editor.setDecorations(addedDecorationType, addedRanges);
    editor.setDecorations(removedDecorationType, removedRanges);

    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Changes have been highlighted.');
}


The issue was that the text decorations were only highlighting on the original text and not on the diff text itself since i haven't added the diff text to the file in the editor, so the fix is simply to make sure you add the diff into the file but hold context to the old text incase the user rejects the changes so you can reverse it back to the original text.

If this is your answer and your not going to give the code changes you did to fix this problem, please just remove the question your self, otherwise update this answer to show the implemented changed to perform what you have said you have done.
